# Plugin- Lombok is not compatible with current version of IDE because it requires 191.* or but current build is AI-212.5712.43

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, lombok

[image]

I tried to download 2 plugins from internet but am not able to judge which will be compatible with Chipmunk Android Studio. Please help

Comment: Did you try to delete .gradle folder then invalid caches&restart ide.

Comment: yes, but didn't worked for every single downloaded jar file it is showing this

Comment: You can check this, when you have time. https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/840

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry folks !! But my problem is resolved, Hope this will help you too if you ever face this issue

Goto- [lombok-compatible-versions](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/1111)

This can help download the Lombok version based on Android studio version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is currently bundled with IntelliJ Idea and not compatible with the latest releases of Android Studio.

I created a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker requesting to include the plugin directly bundled into Android Studio builds.

Whoever agrees, please click <kbd>+1</kbd> (and maybe add a comment too) to give visibility to the request. Let's hope we're lucky and they take it into account. [Lombok plugin support on Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266333624)

For now, as a workaround, we can track current plugin development in [IntelliJ Community Edition repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community). Simply download the proper published IntelliJ release, extract it, and zip the [lombok plugin folder](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/lombok) to install it from disk.

Hope this helps.